# Convergence of $f(p_n)$ insufficient to show continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I came across a problem that asked one to assume $f: M\to N$ is a function from a metric space to another, and that if $(p_n)$ in $M$ converges then $f(p_n)$ in $N$ converges. It asked that one show these assumptions imply continuity of $f$.

My question is doesn't the piecewise function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x), x\neq 2$ and $f(x) = 5, x=2$ contradict that statement since for any sequence $x_n \to 2$, we have $f(x_n)\to 2$ but $f$ is not continuous or is there something wrong with this counterexample?

Thanks!

Comment: If $x \neq 2$, what is $f(x)$?

Comment: $x_{2n} = 2$, and $x_{2n+1} = 2+2^{-n}$.

Comment: f(x) = 5 as stated.

Comment: @DanielFischer ah I see! Thanks!

Comment: Of course, the full condition should be $\lim f(p_n)=f(\lim p_n)$.

Comment: @LutzL No, that is not necessary. If $p_n\to p$ then consider the sequence $q_n$ with $q_{2n}=p_n$ and $q_{2n+1}=p$. If $f(q_n)$ converges, the limit *must* equal $f(p)$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen, I really do not see the difference. The condition must be valid for any convergent sequence. That you give the limit point an extra name does not change the property.

Comment: OK, I see the difference. Your formulation, which is the one of the question, is more abstract, contains a logic riddle, but does not generate more information or generality. So the first step is to show the identity I wrote down via your method of an interlaced sequence.

Comment: @LutzL: Yes, you got it. I like the name “logic riddle” for it; it is not really deep at all.

Comment: @ronald, you have $f(x) = 5$ when $x = 2$, you wrote nothing when it is $x \neq 2$

Answer (score 0):

If you assume $f$ discontinuous at $x$, there's an $\varepsilon >0$ such that in every neighborood of $x$ you can find $y$ with $d(f(x),f(y))>\varepsilon$. Hence you can construct a sequence $x_n$ that converges to $x$, with $f(x_n)$ not converging to $f(x)$.

Comment: Yes, but that is beside the point.

Comment: Why? It's a simple proof of the theorem in question, hence a Counter-Counterexample.

Comment: The point is that even though $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(x)$, it *could* conceivably converge to some other value. The theorem you are proving is easier than what is being asked, though not by much.

Comment: Ah I see the point. Well if we admit sequences that assume the value $x$, then the fact that the limit $f(t)_{t\to x}$ must equal $f(x)$ is trivial. Since the theorem is a statement of continuity I unconsciounsly assumed that one (and hence all) of the limits $f(x_n)$ was equal to $f(x)$. If one doesn't make one of these two extra requirement, actually the function may even not be defined in $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Given the added condition that lim f(p_n) = f(lim p_n) you can show that for any S contained in M, f of the closure of S is contained in the closure of f of S. This is often used as the definition of continuity of functions between topological spaces.